# How BrowserRouter pass otherProps to Router (react-router library)

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

this question is for learning purpose

```
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from "history";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import warning from "tiny-warning";

/**
 * The public API for a <Router> that uses HTML5 history.
 */
class BrowserRouter extends React.Component {
  history = createHistory(this.props);

  render() {
    return <Router history={this.history} children={this.props.children} />;
  }
}

if (__DEV__) {
  BrowserRouter.propTypes = {
    basename: PropTypes.string,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    forceRefresh: PropTypes.bool,
    getUserConfirmation: PropTypes.func,
    keyLength: PropTypes.number
  };

  BrowserRouter.prototype.componentDidMount = function() {
    warning(
      !this.props.history,
      "<BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, " +
        "use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`."
    );
  };
}

export default BrowserRouter;
```

taken from [github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js)

if you check these lines:

```
class BrowserRouter extends React.Component {
  history = createHistory(this.props);

  render() {
    return <Router history={this.history} children={this.props.children} />;
  }
}
```

BrowserRouter does not pass other props like "basename" to Router, so how is "basename" going to take effect?

Comment: You will probably find the answer to your question by looking at the code of `createBrowserHistory` function from the `history` package that React Router uses.

Comment: searching "basename" in history library result in nothing

Comment: yeah, i looked at the code of `createBrowserHistory` function as well but i also didn't find any information on how the arguments passed from `BrowserRouter` are used by this function.

Comment: ya, but "basename" and others props are stated in the API doc https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string